# Index Inside If with Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to reference just one area of a named formula and return it as an array. This is so I can then count the number of rows in the areas referenced and eventually sum them. I going to eventually integrate the results of this into a pretty complicated mess of other formulas that automatically join and rank multiple matrices. I am trying to do this using formulas, not VBA, as a portability requirement. Some folks are a bit weary about running other folks code...

For now, though, I've come up with a simple example. Let's pretend that in the name manager we have a formula named `Letters` that is defined as:

```
=A1:A4,C1:C6
```

The range `A1:A4` contains the letters "A" through ."D" and the range `C1:C6` contains the letters "E" through "J".

If I write a simple `INDEX` formula I can return the first or second area of `Letters` like so:

```
=INDEX(Letters,,,1)
=INDEX(Letters,,,2)
```

I know this works by doing an F9 in on the formula and it returns the expected array of letters (`{"A";"B";"C";"D"}` or `{"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J"}`) for the appropriate area. But doing it this way makes the assumption that there will always be two areas in `Letters`. I'd like to keep my formula dynamic in case I was to add another area. I can create another formula named `Letters_Areas` and make it equal to the following:

```
=ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,AREAS(Letters)))
```

This will return an array with the value of `{1;2}` for the example (or more if there was more areas) and I can pass that to an `IF` to loop like so:

```
=IF(Letters_Areas,INDEX(Letters,,,Letters_Areas)
```

But that doesn't work. It always returns just the first area in `Letters` because `Letters_Areas` in the second argument of the `IF` always returns `1` as the value, not the first and then second value of the array. I guess my question in a formula is:

```
=IF(Letters_Areas,INDEX(Letters,,,What_Do_I_Put_Here))
```

Where `What_Do_I_Put_Here` counts up for each iteration of the `IF` like a `For` loop would in VBA. Essentially, I need to be able to get `i` in my `For i = 1 to 2` in this case inside the `IF`.

I know that the failure is the `Letters_Areas` in the second argument of the `IF` because I can test it. At first glance you would just do it as such:

```
=IF(Letters_Areas,Letters_Areas)
```

This returns the expected `{1,2}`. However, this is misleading because you can find the true behavior by doing this:

```
=IF(Letters_Areas,INDEX(Letters_Areas,Letters_Areas))
```

And this always returns {1,1} which tells me that is the part that is failing.

The final version of the formula, minus the part I cannot figure out should look something like:

```
=IF(Letters_Areas,ROWS(INDEX(Letters,,,What_Do_I_Put_Here)))
```

And in our test example this would return `{4;6}`. Again, stuck using no VBA. Any ideas?

Comment: If your ranges are filled, and if each area is a single column, then the number of rows would be the same as the number of occupied cells, which can be returned by `=COUNTA(Letters)`.  But I have not been able to figure out how to coerce the `INDEX` function to return multiple areas. You'd need a formula like `=INDEX(Letters,0,0,{1,2}`.  Replacing the array constant with `N(IF(1,{1,2}))` will work to coerce multiple returns for rows or columns, but doesn't seem to work for areas.  This would be trivial in VBA, of course.

Comment: Ron - I figured the dereferencing with `N(IF(1,{1,2}))` would work as well. No such luck. The only formulas I know that deal with areas at all are `INDEX` and `AREAS`. Maybe there's another, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this formula to count areas, assuming that your areas always begin in row 1 as in your example: COLUMNS(A1:Z1)-(SUM(IF(ISBLANK(A1:Z1),1,0)))? Any non-blank cells within that range will be counted as an area and will give the correct count. I am not sure if this is what you are seeking according to your question.

Comment: Roger - In this instance, I can get the number of areas using the `AREAS` function just fine. It's the step where I want to use `INDEX` in as an array formula using only the areas parameter that fails.